# GCM app not installing to emulator when it's Run/debug

Tags: android, trace

so, I basically was following this tutorial step by step
http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/demo.html
I made the server give me the "No devices registered!"
all I have to do is make the app launch, that is where my problem start.
log cat registers:

```
"Trace - error opening trace file: no such file or directory (2)
AndroidRunTime - Shutting Down VM
dalvikvm - threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
AndroidRunTime - FATAL EXCEPTION: main"
```

MANIFEST:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <permission
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
    <uses-permission
        android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

    <!-- Main activity. -->
    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".DemoActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver
            android:name="com.google.android.gcm.GCMBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
            <intent-filter>
                <!-- Receives the actual messages. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
                <!-- Receives the registration id. -->
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
                <category android:name="com.google.android.gcm.demo.app" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

By the way, I imported the project to make sure that the problem is not from my lousy programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure it's Google API emulator. Also login with a gmail account in the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

To run GCM on emulator you need to create google account on your emulator. HAve you create it?
The emulator shows only shows the message in Logcat on successful execution

Answer (score -1):

If you have followed all the guides in GCM demo app, then you can capture your uncaught exceptions with this:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Process;

public class ExceptionHandler implements UncaughtExceptionHandler{

    public ExceptionHandler() {
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread thread, Throwable ex) {

            // capture the exception information 

        Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
        System.exit(0);
    }

  }
```

And in your main activity :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new ExceptionHandler());
}
```